# In flutter, How to use network image multiple time without calling again?

Tags: image, flutter, networking

I am fetching image  in one page. Using..

Image.network(url).

I want to use this same image in different screens without calling again. How to achieve that?

Comment: you need to get it, then store it,  then use it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image). It saves the image after loading and caches it for further usage. If the image hasn't been loaded for a while (e.g. a few sessions), the package tages care of it automatically and will remove it from the cache.

Add it to your pubspec.yaml and then use:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: url,
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in device storage by using packages or simply save it on ram(removes after closing app or widget or etc.) and use it where you want.
If you are trying to save it on ram you should pass that image between screens those need that image.

Answer (score -1):

Make another file, say `get_image.dart`, and make a function inside it that will return the network image, like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

getImage() => Image.network(url);
```

call this `getImage()` function wherever you want this image, like this:

```
image: getImage(),
```